# The view system.views.Login didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: mysql, django

I'm newbie to Django. I'm stuck at one thing that, valueError at /login/. I've tried my best to search and try to solve this but i didn't find my problem solution. In Following First Code Sample From Which I Got Error,

```
class Login(View):
    template = 'login.html'
    form = forms.LoginForm
    
    def get(self, request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            username = request.user
            stud = Stud.objects.filter(adm=username).exists()
            cord = Cord.objects.filter(staff_no=username).exists()
            if stud:
                return redirect('appStatus')
            elif cord:
                return redirect('cordIndex')
            else:
                return redirect('admin')
        else:
            form = self.form(None)
            return render(request, self.template, {'form': form})
            
    def post(self, request):
        form = self.form(request.POST)
        
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
    
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
       
            stud = Stud.objects.filter(adm=username).exists()
            cord = Cord.objects.filter(staff_no=username).exists()
            adv = adv.objects.filter(staff_no=username).exists()
       
            if stud:
                return redirect('studIndex')
            elif cord:
                return redirect('cordIndex')
            elif adv:
                return redirect('advIndex')
        else:
            context ={
                'form': self.form(request.POST),
                'errors': 'Either username or password is wrong'               
            }
            return render(request, self.template, context)
```

Error traced from terminal:

```
ValueError: The view system.views.Login didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
```

Comment: Can you pleas share the full view `Login`?

Comment: Yea dear, I have added the full login view

Comment: Inside the block `if user is not None:`, you don't have an else statement. So this error is not only a possibility, but a reality if none of those `exists()` return True

Comment: it has not  worked